# how to solve 'Adding file to index' has encountered a problem in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, github

I am having problem with eclipse on my laptop while I want to add a project to index(for github). I get this error: Failed to add resource to index
Failed to add resource to index
Exception caught during execution of add command

this is my log:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 4 0 2023-01-25 20:38:42.622
!MESSAGE Failed to add resource to index
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Failed to add resource to index
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.AddToIndexOperation.execute(AddToIndexOperation.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.actions.AddToIndexActionHandler$1.run(AddToIndexActionHandler.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.JGitInternalException: Exception caught during execution of add command
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.AddCommand.call(AddCommand.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.AddToIndexOperation.execute(AddToIndexOperation.java:74)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.LockFailedException: Cannot lock C:\Users\motah\.git\index. Ensure that no other process has an open file handle on the lock file C:\Users\motah\.git\index.lock, then you may delete the lock file and retry.
    at org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.DirCache.lock(DirCache.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.DirCache.lock(DirCache.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.DirCache.lock(DirCache.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Repository.lockDirCache(Repository.java:1285)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.RepositoryHandle.lockDirCache(RepositoryHandle.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.AddCommand.call(AddCommand.java:122)
    ... 3 more
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.egit.core 4 0 2023-01-25 20:38:42.622
!MESSAGE Failed to add resource to index
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.JGitInternalException: Exception caught during execution of add command
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.AddCommand.call(AddCommand.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.AddToIndexOperation.execute(AddToIndexOperation.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.actions.AddToIndexActionHandler$1.run(AddToIndexActionHandler.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.LockFailedException: Cannot lock C:\Users\motah\.git\index. Ensure that no other process has an open file handle on the lock file C:\Users\motah\.git\index.lock, then you may delete the lock file and retry.
    at org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.DirCache.lock(DirCache.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.DirCache.lock(DirCache.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.DirCache.lock(DirCache.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Repository.lockDirCache(Repository.java:1285)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.RepositoryHandle.lockDirCache(RepositoryHandle.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.AddCommand.call(AddCommand.java:122)
    ... 3 more
```

Can anyone help me here how I can solve it?
I have deleted my project and made another one and it did not work. I did with other projects that I have and I get the same error.
I am learning how to push in eclipse to github. I only had this problem at class and we could not solve it.

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. [Edit] your question to show us the extra detail.

Comment: Thanks for saying it. I just solved it looking in .log messeages.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution. I had to delete .lock file. Now it works fine.